# Как понять, что не так с ответом?

Tags: обсуждение

> Поясните пожалуйста, что я сделал не так или не сделал, а может не доделал.

Был задан вопрос "Как обойтись без вызова анонимной функции" в контексте задачи "нужно создать функцию которая принимает число как аргумент и возвращает другую функцию которая также принимает число как аргумент и возвращает сумму."(javaScript) 
[Вот собственно вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1466364/callback-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Я дал развернутый ответ, как можно этого достичь с разными примерами и вариантами.

И получил за это от кого то минус.

Мне, по большому счету, по барабану за понижение репы, но очень хочется понять, за что этот минус прилетел?
Слишком много вариантов привожу? Что то не учел? Сделал лишний пример(но мне всегда казалось, что чем больше информации в контексте вопроса или около того, тем лучше).

Одним словом, хочу понять, где я допустил оплошность в своем ответе?

Comment: хулиганят. На такой ответ не очевидный минус. Но я не помню java, так что оценить не смогу...

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе просят функцию, которая возвращает функцию. Только первый и последний примеры из ответа это делают, зачем нужны остальные - непонятно. При этом последний использует асинхронность, которая тут вообще не в тему.

Через bind действительно можно сделать, но не так, как ты написал. Про объекты в вопросе ничего нет, и причин как-то использовать this я тоже не вижу.

В общем, ответ выглядит как свалка рандомной информации, которая верна (кроме процитированного ниже), но никак не относится к вопросу.

> Где значение параметра a первой функции уже будет сохранено как константа во второй функции.

А с чего как константа-то? Как переменная - ей можно присвоить другое значение, если захотеть.