# Что не так с моим ответом?

Tags: поддержка, ответы, нытьё, голоса-против

Я дал вроде как вполне развёрнутый и понятный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490868/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81/1491222#1491222) на вопрос. Но на мой вопрос поставили "минус", без каких-либо комментариев. Я уже прочитал [это обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), но я не нашёл тех частых проблем в своём ответе, которые были обозначены в том обсуждении. Подскажите, что не так с моим ответом =(?

P.S. вопрос про конкретный ответ, поэтому я не считаю мой вопрос дубликатом [этого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) или [этого](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12222/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ развернутый и понятный, но не по теме вопроса. Автор спрашивает, как автоматизировать добавление новых языков в языковую панель, а вы пишете что-то общее про обзор разных способов написания скриптов в Windows. При этом вряд ли скриптовые языки помогут решить задачу, учитывая, что автору нужны глобальные горячие клавиши. Соответственно, понадобится написать что-то вроде резидентной программы на полноценном языке программирования. Автор не указал, на каком языке программирования он хочет ответ, но нужно было это уточнить в комментариях, а не отвечать наугад про все подряд.

Вообще, фразы типа "Тут не нужно ничего изучать, просто гуглите нужные вам команды", "Я о нём слышал только краем уха, поэтому рекомендую почитать в интернете" - явный признак ответа, который будет магнитом для минусов. Смысл написания ответа в том, чтобы те, кто "гуглят", находили и приходили почитать именно его. Словом, ответ должен давать информацию по теме вопроса, а не направление, где теоретически такая информация есть.

> Я уже прочитал это обсуждение на мете, но я не нашёл тех частых проблем в своём ответе, которые были обозначены в том обсуждении.

На мете вы вряд ли найдете объяснения, почему тот или иной ответ плох, слишком все специфично для каждой метки, типа вопроса и т.п. Лучше читайте популярные заплюсованные ответы и берите пример с них.

Comment: Спасибо, я действительно неправильно понял вопрос.